# Is it possible to transform a key value from a map in a param object?

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary

I have a map in which I put a key value like this:

```
  for (let controller of this.attributiFormArray.controls) {
     
      attributiAttivitaMap.set(controller.get('id').value,  { value: controller.get('valoreDefault').value, mandatory: controller.get('obbligatorio').value })
  }
```

and this is my map after the set:

```
0 : key: 10, value: {value: 200, mandatory: false}
1 : key: 102, value: {value: 300, mandatory: false}
```

Ok now my porpuse is to create a list of object like this:

```
"valoriDefaultAttributiAttivita" : {
    "10" : {"value" : "200", "mandatory": false},
    "102" : {"value" : "300", "mandatory": false},

 }
```

where the numbers "10", "102" are the keys of my map.

I tried in several ways but when I try to put it in array for example it doesn't allow me to set my value of key like a property.

```
 let array: any[] = [];
 for(let key of attributiAttivitaMap.keys()){
    array.push({key: attributiAttivitaMap.get(key)});
 }
```

How I can do this?

Comment: your expected output is an object, not an array. your map is pretty similar to your expected output, so what are you trying to achieve? a list of objects or an object which keys are the "key" value from your map?

Comment: an object which the keys are the value of key maps

Comment: mmh it's a problem when I build the project. It shows me --->   ',' expected.
        key['key']: attributiAttivitaMap.get(key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to get the same map but in form of js object, you can do following

```
const map = new Map<number, { value: number; mandatory: boolean }>();

map.set(10, { value: 200, mandatory: false });
map.set(102, { value: 300, mandatory: false });

const obj: Record<number, { value: number; mandatory: boolean }> = {};

map.forEach((val, key) => obj[key] = val);
```

Or iterate through map entries

```
for(const [key, value] of map.entries()) {
  obj[key] = value;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4wLwzAUwO4wLLIA8YArnAEaYBOANDAN4wBuCANiZgFwZmVUDc8BGAAmCKCCoBPbuRAhWmYTAC+APgAUASn4AoXYiQA6CJigaAjAAY6jFuy4wATFZtDR4yTJgAzNqdUdA2QTM0srJ1tmNg5uAGZXOkQPCWluP1YAlSDdUEhYEHIAK24AJUxQKhFiXmoo+1ieCmpBZLFU7zkFJTBVNTQGFT1g4x9JAFEEYAALDQ17OgBrTCktNH7CooBtZakAXQH7HLGqDTzoGB2VugbMA5AfIWNMMCgqAEtMCG01+l0YGCbK77Q4xTB6FRAA)